# Finding number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct blue balls & $nt$ distinct red balls s.t. between any two blue balls there are exactly $t$ red balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Using combinatorics, determine the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct blue balls and $n·t$ distinct red balls in a row, such that between any two blue balls there are exactly $t$ red balls.

This is my thought process:
 there are $n!$ ways to order the blue balls in a line. Between each blue ball there are $n-1$ slots + $2$ sides at a total of $n+1$ slots. To arrange $n$ red ball groups (of $t$ balls) we can do $n+1$ choose $n$, i.e., $\binom{n+1}{n}$. Finally, we need to arrange the different red balls inside each and every group from here I'm stuck....

I'm not sure if it is ok to arrange all $t·n$ red balls in a line and then to find how many groups in size $t$ we have. We don't have any answers so whatever I do I don't know what is the real result.

Comment: If there are $k$ red balls before the first blue ball, then there are $t-k$ red balls after the last blue ball.

Comment: No such arrangement is possible if $n\ge3$ and $t\gt0$. Call the blue balls $B_1,B_2 \dots,B_n$ from left to right. If there are $t$ red balls between $B_1$ and $B_2$, and $t$ red balls between $B_2$ and $B_3$, then there are $2t$ red balls between $B_1$ and $B_2$. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you have exactly $~n + nt = n(t+1)~$ spaces to fill.

Per the problem constraint, the first blue ball must go into position $~k~$ from the left, where $~k~$ is some element in $\{1,2,3,\cdots,t+1\}.$

It is then presumed that every subsequent blue ball will be placed exactly $~(t+1)~$ positions after the previous blue ball.

So, at one extreme, the blue balls are placed in positions 
$\{1, ~1 + (t+1), ~1 + (2t+2), ~\cdots, ~1 + (n-1)(t+1) = [n(t+1)] - t\}.$

At the other extreme, the blue balls are shifted exactly $~t~$ places to the right, so that the first blue ball is at position $~(t+1),~$ and the last blue ball is at position $~n(t+1).$

So, you can reserve the factor of $~(t+1)~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the blue balls are positioned at 
$\{1, ~1 + (t+1), ~1 + (2t+2), ~\cdots, ~1 + (n-1)(t+1) = [n(t+1)] - t\}.$

This means that with the factor of $~(t+1)~$ reserved, the positions of the blue balls and the positions of the non-blue balls are now rigidly determined.

---

It remains only to accommodate that all of the blue balls are considered distinguishable, as are all of the non-blue balls.

This is accommodated by recognizing that the blue balls may be permuted in $~n!~$ ways, and the non-blue balls may be permuted in $~(nt)!~$ ways.

Therefore, the final answer is

$$(t+1) \times n! \times [(nt)!].$$

**Note**:
This answer assumes that there is no constraint on how many non-blue balls immediately precede the first blue ball, or immediately follow the last blue ball.

Answer (score 0):

*User2661923 has got the same answer before me, I have just explained differently*

To simplify presentation, I shall firstly use some numbers rather than symbols so that I can explain diagrammatically, and finally put the answer into the original symbols.

Suppose  $n =4$ blue balls and $t = 6$

so you have a configuration $\boxed{\color{blue}1}\boxed{\color{red}6}\boxed{\color{blue}1}\boxed{\color{red}6}\boxed{\color{blue}1}\boxed{\color{red}6}\boxed{\color{blue}1}$

But $6$ red balls are surplus, and considering the configuration in the diagram as a bar, by stars and bars the surplus $6$ can be placed in $\binom{6+1}1 = 7$ ways, $0-6,\,1-5,\,....6-0$
thus the entire red balls can be placed in $7$ ways

Since each ball is distinct, we now permute them in their places in $7*4!24!$ ways

Transmuting this to the original notation,

$$\large{(t+1)n!(nt)!}$$